# How to run Broadcast receiver in context of a service

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

I have an application which has 2 processes (a) One which runs the main activity and (b) that runs the service.

As the service is running as a separate process, is it possible to attach a broadcast receiver to the service process so that when broadcast receiver catches system intents like boot completed the service process is scheduled rather than the main activity process.

Comments....

Comment: "I have an application which has 2 processes" -- why? Why are you wasting RAM, CPU, and battery? Why is this in the user's interests?

Comment: Let me rephrase it. I have an application which hosts an activity and a service. The service is described in manifest as android:process=":. What I understand is that the service and activity(when active) will run as diff processes. I need the service for some background task. The background task has trigger points at phone backlight off, phone lock, boot etc.. For each of the events if the bcast receiver is called in the context of main application process the receiver has to again pass the intent to the service process. So as per my understanding 2 processes would be scheduled instead of one

Comment: Since you do not need two processes to have an activity and a service, my question still stands: why do you think this is good for the user?

Comment: the service be running in background irrespective of activity in front. what is the issue in it ? please explain

Comment: "the service be running in background irrespective of activity in front" -- that will happen, by default, with a single process. Get rid of your `android:process` attributes, and you will discover that your app will work just fine. Moreover, it will consume less CPU, RAM, and battery, which will make the users happier. There are *very* few situations in Android where having multiple processes for an app is acceptable behavior, and you have provided no evidence that your app involves one of those situations.